# Scaner Epson L375 series

Tags: scanner, epson

i am from Brazil, i have a Epson L375 and when i scaner the press do not save the file in no any format, but the press show the image of the archive, only do not save.

PS: Ubuntu 16.04

Versão em português
Version in portguese

Oi, eu sou do brasil, eu tenho uma Epson L375 e quando eu scaneio a impressora não salva o arquivo em nenhum formato, mas a impressora mostra a imagem do arquivo, apenas não salva.

Comment: I understand this to mean "the scanner gets an image of the page on to the screen but the image of the page isn't saved."

Comment: What program are you using? Usually you get a first quick scan to check the page looks OK, then you do a full scan which takes much longer and allows saving the image.

Comment: The programm used is the Epson official driver to L375 series, and the grafical interface is named Image Scan. Epson Image Scan on ubuntu 16.04 to L375 Series do not save the file of the scaner. Sorry i speak portuguese.

Comment: When you can see the file on the screen, could you take a screenshot (usually PrintScreen button next to F12) and upload it so we can see what you're seeing. You might want to try an different scanning application, perhaps `skanlite`.

Comment: The solution was use outher driver and outher software. The driver used was wifi drver, and the software was Simple Scan.